# How to make a decent UI

Tags: android-layout, android

Please I need help on how to create a nice looking UI. Now I suppose that people looking at this question have an android, if so go to the market. Download a app called, "Quick Settings". It has a great UI and I want to learn how to make mine look as good as that one, if you have any kind of help, it would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to narrow things down way more than this.  There is no answer to "how do I make an awesome app".

Comment: I am just asking on how to make a UI better....

Comment: Define better. What UI? To show what? To receive what input?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick Google search brings up lots of good tips, tricks and tools for designing Android UIs.  Here are a few:

- http://www.droiddraw.org/
- http://www.androiduipatterns.com/
- http://phandroid.com/2011/05/11/10-tips-for-android-ui-design/

Comment: DroidDraw is perfect, thanks!

Comment: Relevant - http://www.slideshare.net/the100rabh/making-your-ui-look-good-on-android